# Websites for mobile browsers: CSS and meta tags

Tags: mobile, css, html, ipad

Some sites do not work in mobile browsers. Often this is caused by specific CSS attributes or missing HTML meta tags.

For example the HTML tag `<meta name="viewport"...>` is required for correct scaling of the page. Or the CSS attribute `overflow: scroll;` in a `div` on the page does not work on iPad as expected.

What specific Tags/Attributes does a HTML developer need to understand and use when enabling a page for mobile browsers?

Comment: This strikes as a web programming question, not a user interface question.

Comment: @Witek Try asking on stackoverflow.com or doctype.com. This site is for design questions, not implementation questions.

Comment: A very good resource for people interested in mobile browsers is [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/). The blog section regularly has excellent articles about the changing state of the mobile world, and developer articles about how to code for mobile browsers. He also has a set of browser compatibility tables which are very handy for seeing which features you can use in which browsers/platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The world is mobile, we as user interface experts have to rise to the challenge and face the future!*

A couple of **awesome** resources to look at for developing mobile sites are the [opera dev teams articles](http://dev.opera.com/articles/mobile/) & W3C [standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-mobile/) on CSS for Mobiles.

Answer (score 1):

meta tags for mobiles

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta http-equiv="x-rim-auto-match" content="none">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
```